# Laravel http request: Cannot run multiple request

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest

I got terrible problem with Laravel http request. Please help me to solve this:

I assumed that I have 2 requests that route to **same Controller**:

- **Req 1:** http://localhost:8000/manualScheduler/runScript?task_name=Task (This request takes much time to run around 2mins)
- **Req 2:**http://localhost:8000/manualScheduler/detail?task_name=Task  ( this one is very quick)

When I fired **Req 1** then next is **Req 2**. I just think that 2 Reqs are separately, means **Req 1** and **Req 2** run in their own way. But the result I got was **Req 2** could not finish when **Req 1** was running.

In controller,

- Req 1: I want to run script to parse HTML file with yangqi/htmldom
- Req 2: I want to return some simple value.

**Edited:** My question is why my Req 2 has to wait Req 1 finish first? They should not depend on each other, i think? Or some problem with Laravel.

Thanks for your support,

Comment: Can you edit your text so it has clear question in it that we can answer? Right now I am not entirely sure what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Edited, Could you please help me on this? @smartman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using default local synchronous queue driver. To get parallel processing capability you need to use some other driver. I recommend iron.io

More info from http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#configuration

Comment: You mean laravel server in local cannot handle parallel processing? How about server in host, ex: byethost,etc..? Do we need to configure anything?

Comment: It depends on your config. Sync driver means that tasks are processed in sequence. Other drivers support also parallel processing. The link I gave you explains how to use different queue drivers that you can configure in your config/queue.php

Comment: 1 more question, how can I execute function by Req 1 in background (thread)? Can you give me some hint?

Comment: I recommend to use iron queue driver http://www.iron.io/mq for parallel processing. I have been using it and it works like a charm. However in localhost you need to create publicly accessible tunnel so that calls made from iron.io servers reach your application. You can also try database driver.

Comment: Thanks all. But I still have some confusion. Before that, I just think that in default server will handle requests parallel, separately, not single thread like this, I think every incoming request will work in their thread only? Am I correct?

Comment: If you are using sync driver then all the tasks will be done in one thread within current request.
If you are using iron.io then each of the requests are handled in parallel independent from eachother. It just depends what timing the iron.io will use to call your server. Usually the calls are made immediately so both of the tasks should start processing fraction of a second after you set them and work in parallel asynchronously in background while your request is done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what happen if I use "null"? As document, they said that it will not handle as queue, so it will not handle request?