# Laravel run multiple HTTP request each minute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I run a Laravel HTTP request it runs through a controller that process my request, but for example when `request1` runs, it takes 2 minutes to process. But if I run a second one, `request2` that will process in 1 second it will not execute `request2` before `request1` is finished.

I looked at the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#configuration) but I can't find any solutions.

Does someone has a solution?

Comment: Can you provide details i.e. code and screenshot of request

Comment: @MuhammadKashifAbbasi is it not possible to run 2 or more http requests at the same time?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790713/laravel-http-request-cannot-run-multiple-request